# How to store file information into an array?

Tags: bash, scripts, files

With this part of script I can get a necessary information about files in my directory(and subdirectories). The only information I need is the extension and the size of file.

```
for file in `find . -type f`; do
   size=$(stat -c '%s' ${file})
   file=$(echo "${file}" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
   ext=$(echo "${file}" | grep '..*\.' | awk -F. '{print $NF}' | grep '[A-Za-z0-9]')
if [ -z ${ext} ]; then
   echo "NOTE: no extention"
else
   EXTS="${EXTS}${ext}${newLine}"
```

It is only part of the script. So my question is: How can I put this informarion into an array? I mean I want an array with elements to look like this:

```
 c/123 /12 h/90 /0 txt/0
```

where c, h and txt are file extension and 123, 12 and 0 are file sizes. So lately I can separately work with sizes and extensions
I hope, I've neatly put my question down. Sorry for mistakes. :)

Comment: This identical question is cross-posted to U&L http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272515/how-to-store-file-information-into-an-array See also: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1480/cross-posting-questions-that-are-on-topic-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [don't do `for file in $(find …)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). That's very fragile.

Now, you can simplify your code a bit by getting find to print the filenames and sizes together, using `-printf`:

```
find . -type f -printf '%s.%f/'
```

Then, you can use `awk` to process this output to get cumulative sizes by extension. Note that I used `.` to separate the filename (`%f`) from the size (`%s`), and I added a `/` after that. Hence, I can use `.` as a field separator in `awk`. And since the only characters not allowed in filenames are `/` and the ASCII NUL, I can safely use `/` as the record separator.

So:

```
awk -F. -v RS=/ 'NF > 2 {size[$NF] += $1; next}
  {size["/"] += $1}
END {for (i in size) {print i,"/",size[i]}'
```

Here, I'm using `/` as the index if there's no extension.

Combined:

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%s.%f/' | awk -F. -v RS=/ 'NF > 2 {size[$NF] += $1; next}
{size["/"] += $1}
END {for (i in size) {printf "%s/%d\n", i, size[i]}}'
h/780
md/2509
tex/23961
c/13557
//5109
txt/2349291
sh/1166
py/12248
```

Now, if your extensions don't contain spaces, you could just do:

```
my_array=( $(find . -type f -printf '%s.%f/' | awk -F. -v RS=/ 'NF > 2 {size[$NF] += $1; next} {size["/"] += $1} END {for (i in size) {printf "%s/%d\n", i, size[i]}}') )
```

Or, you can use process substitution and read each entry in:

```
my_arr=()
while IFS='' read -r entry
do
    my_arr+=( "$entry" )
done < <(find . -type f -printf '%s.%f/' | awk -F. -v RS=/ 'NF > 2 {size[$NF] += $1; next} {size["/"] += $1} END {for (i in size) {printf "%s/%d\n", i, size[i]}}')
```

As before:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${my_arr[@]}"
h/780
md/2509
tex/23961
c/13557
//5109
txt/2349291
sh/1166
py/12248
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short bash script what is doing the job:

```
i=0
while read -r -d $'\0' file
do
   size=$(stat -c '%s' ${file})
   ext=`basename $file | sed -re "s/^[^.]+.*\.//"`

   if [ -z "$ext" ] || [ "$ext" = "`basename $file`" ] ; then
      echo "NOTE: no extention ($file)"
   else
     extensions[$i]="$ext"
     sizes[$((i++))]=$size
   fi
done < <(find . -type f -print0)

for (( j=0 ; j<i; j++ )) do
  echo index: $j / extension: ${extensions[$j]} / size: ${sizes[$j]}
done
```

Comment: I understand , you want to answer questions and gain as much rep as possible, but don't cross post the same answer, just like OP cross posted his question. That's  unacceptable.

Comment: If I interested in much rep as possible I would answer more questions... You are free to delete all posts you dont like....